# Semitranslucent keycap set

Tags: keyboards, led

I'm looking for a keycap set with semitranslucent keys. Let me explain this:

Originally I was looking for a blank keycap set. However, I have a backlit keyboard, so this felt kind of like a waste of a great feature. So I was looking for translucent keycap sets, however they didn't look very well. Then I thought of keys that look just like my normal keycaps (i.e. only the letter is translucent) but with something like dots instead of the letters. Then I'd still have the blank style and use the backlight and it would hopefully look well.

However, I was unable to find something similiar in the internet, which astonished me, as there generally is a pretty wide selection of keycap sets out there.

Do you have any ideas?

EDIT: I actually found this option on [maxkeyboard](http://www.maxkeyboard.com/keyboard-keycap-services.html), however this costs $90, which seems quite a lot of money for keycaps with a translucent dot atop of it. Are there any cheaper solutions out there?

Answer (score 0):

Max Products has a variety of keycaps and does [custom keycaps](http://www.maxkeyboard.com/products/cherry-mx-keycap/).

On their order page for customization it says: "Upload your design using our print template gives you total control on your own text/icon. We support both Adobe illustrator or Inkscape (SVG) format.".

If you want: "... keys that look just like my normal keycaps (i.e. only the letter is translucent) but with something like dots instead of the letters." - it looks like they can do it.

They also manufacture complete working keyboards of various styles and different layouts for different countries. Here's an example of a keyboard with semi-transluscent characters:

[image: PBT Double Shot 104-key Black Top White Translucent Side Wall Backlight Keycap Set]

Comment: I didn't know they support semi-transparent artwork files - thank you, I'll try this.

Comment: See my original post for further information.

Comment: @MetaColon - Thanks for informing me that you updated your question. It's unfortunate that SE doesn't automatically inform people when the question is altered, I appreciate your effort.